# How to exclude images from regex email pattern?

Tags: regex, go

I am using this regex: `\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b` that I found from https://emailregex.com.

However, it results in images such as **175x100@3x.jpg** to be counted as an email.

I did some searching and found that I could utilize negative look-ahead but the GoLang regexp package does not offer this functionality. Is there any alternative regex pattern in which I could use?

Comment: What is "bad" about `175x100@3x.jpg`? Because it starts with `\d+x\d+@` or because it ends with `.jpg`? What negative lookahead did you try? Surely it won't work in Go regex, but it may throw light on what exactly you mean to do.

Comment: Because it ends with `.jpg`. If it was `175x175@email.com` then i'd be fine with that.

Comment: So, there are two ways. Either check all matches that end with `.jpg`, and if they do, discard them. Or use a regex with an alternation, like `\b(?:[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.jpe?g|([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}))\b` and only collect Group 1 values that exist.

Comment: this is valid email. you have another problem.

Comment: .jpg is a valid domain extension?

Comment: .jpg is syntactically a valid domain extension. And some day it may be a registerable one.

Comment: If your goal is to reject invalid email addresses and not just ones that happen to look like an image filename, then check the top-level domain against [the IANA TLD list](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt).

Answer (score 0):

You may match any extensions you wish to ignore and then match and capture the TLD pattern. If Group 1 value is not empty, take the match, else discard it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := ` 175x100@3x.jpg and  175x100@3x.com`
    rex := regexp.MustCompile(`\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|([A-Za-z]{2,6}))\b`)
    results := rex.FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
    for _, match := range results  {
        if len(match[1]) > 0 {
          fmt.Printf("%q\n", match[0])
        }
    }
}
```

See the [Go demo online](https://play.golang.org/p/bsGMRF_eV7t). Output: `175x100@3x.com`.

Here, the `(?:jpe?g|([A-Za-z]{2,6}))` pattern matches `jpg` or `jpeg`, and matches and *captures* into Group 1 any two to six ASCII letters. `if len(match[1]) > 0 { fmt.Printf("%q\n", match[0]) }` part prints the match only if Group 1 matched.